# Using a UNCalendarNotificationTrigger with dateMatching produces a trigger date 5 hours after the intended time

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, notifications, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to schedule an iOS notification at the same hour and minute every day.

First I define a `DateComponents`:

```
var components = DateComponents()
components.hour = 1
components.minute = 10
components.second = 0
```

Then use this to make the trigger:

```
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
```

Printing the components yields the expected result:

```
hour: 1 minute: 10 second: 0 isLeapMonth: false
```

But printing the trigger's next trigger date always shows a time 5 hours later than what it should:

```
Optional(2017-07-18 06:10:00 +0000)
```

Any idea what's going on here? I've tried setting the time zone on the components and it doesn't have any effect.

Edit: It looks like the notifications are actually firing at the correct time (I had a different issue which had broken them). I still can't explain the behavior of nextFireDate though.

Comment: An advice when working with `Date / NSDate`: watch your timezone. `6:10 GMT` is `1:10` local time if you happen to be in the `GMT+5` timezone

Comment: Definitely had trouble with that before, but here I'm not using Date at all, just DateComponents. Also not in GMT+5 zone. Adding a time zone to the DateComponents doesn't have an effect on the 5 hour difference.

Comment: You scheduled your notification for 1:10am in your time zone, which is apparently 6:10am GMT. I’m inferring from this that you must be in GMT-5 time zone and it’s telling you that the timer will fire at 1:10am local time. But you’re suggesting that you’re not in GMT-5 time zone? If not, what time zone are you?

Comment: I'm in GMT-6. It looks like the notifications are actually firing at the correct time, and only nextTriggerDate is wrong. I had a different issue in my program that was preventing them from working, but assumed it was because of this.